# Is there a way to trace PHP errors logged from Rules?

Tags: rules, debugging

Occasionally I'm seeing an error in the error_log

```
[10-Apr-2015 10:16:45 America] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Some text' (T_STRING) in /home/simulab1/public_html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

This could be coming from any number of Rules we have. Is there any way to pin this down to the specific Rule in question?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If Xdebug is installed in the machine, it dumps a stack trace to your Apache logs. That might give you a better hint at the context.

If that fails, look at all your Commerce rules and try to find the one with a execute PHP action.